# How can activate C syntax highlighted in VIM?

Tags: linux, gcc, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have an image with CentOS, GCC compiler, and VIM editor. With a long period time ago i achieved to activate C syntax highlighted but i don't remember how, if you could help ?

Comment: `sy on`? Also, filetypes not enabled?

Comment: Any reason for the unaccept? does the answer not work?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.vimrc` file in your home directory with the following contents.

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

The next time you open up a c file you should have syntax highlighting enabled.